# Monitor process with normal access

Tags: c#, process, elevated-privileges

I wrote a program that work perfectly fine in dev, but when I try it on my prod server, I have an Access Denied:

```
ManagementEventWatcher processStartEvent = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
processStartEvent.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(processStartEvent_EventArrived);
processStartEvent.Start();
```

Basically, what I need to achieve is to monitor new process but with a normal account. I did some research and I found that WMI queries required elevated access, which I can't provide to my application.

I removed the were part in my query but it's a process started by the actual user. I need the application to execute some tasks each time that this process is started.

Comment: You aren't monitoring a process. You are tracking *all* process start events. That's kind of an elevated priviledge. Why don't you use *logging*?  Or configure the `Audit Process Tracking` policy and check audit events in the Event log. What do you want to do with such events? You may be able to configure Windows to do it for you. For example, you can specify this setting for all machines in a domain, distribute event subscriptions *with filters* through policy to all of them and have all interesting events appear in a central Event Log. With the option to compress and batch messages too

Comment: I removed the where part from the query. I need the application to run each time that a specific application start.

Comment: In what security-blind world would you allow non-admin users to track what other users are doing on the machine?

Comment: @itsme86, It's his own processes that I need, nothing that the user can't see with the task manager.

Comment: You are *still* reading the process start events for all processes. The filter doesn't change the type of permissions you need. You can't specify permissions *per filter condition*

Comment: @AlexDupuis btw malware runs with the actual user's credentials. Malware by definition is the user's process which is why it's able to do so much damage. And you still haven't explained what you want to do or why you'd need WMI to do it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, is there an other way to monitor only process lunched by current user that would'nt need admin access??

Comment: Have you considered creating a wrapper for the application that does whatever it is you're trying to do in addition to launching the application? Then the user can just launch the application using your wrapper.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, when the application that I monitor start, I need to do some instructions on SQL Server. Any other way than WMI that would raise an event in my app would do it.

Comment: @itsme86, I tried it, I replaced the app with mine that is calling the other one but if it's path/name of the app is not the same, I get an error telling me that the name don't match.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interested in an alternative solution to the polling one posted to keep things event based,

I was successful in getting events with process names and ids without admin privileges using the following query:

```
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN .025 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'";
processWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(@"\\.\root\CIMV2", queryString);
processWatcher.EventArrived += ProcessStartHandler;
processWatcher.Start();
```

Unlike the query you were using, the event received doesn't have most of its properties filled.

However, they are accessible through the event's TargetInstance property.

```
private void ProcessStartHandler(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    var targetInstance = ((System.Management.ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value);
    var processName = targetInstance.Properties["Caption"].Value.ToString();
    var processId   = (uint)targetInstance.Properties["ProcessId"].Value;
    var parentProcessId = (uint)targetInstance.Properties["ParentProcessId"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative option, I'll give it a try next time I revisite this code... which I didn't did in the past 4 years :D If it work in my case, it will be really better than a timer :S

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN .025 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"` will get when a process is closed too!

Comment: The problem with __InstanceCreationEvent is that it's an intrinsic event, which means that if a process is created and deleted within the time window, it can be missed entirely. This is okay for some use cases but entirely unacceptable for others. Win32_ProcessStartTrace is an extrinsic event which will never miss a process.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a work arround, not perfect but work in my case. I created a timer and poll the Processes list every X seconds to see if it's there. Since the screen will always be open for more time than my timer, it work.

```
    static void OnTime(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
            timer.Stop();

            try {
                var procs = from a in Process.GetProcesses()
                            where a.ProcessName == procName
                            select a;
                foreach (Process proc in procs) {
                    ProcessTask(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                }
            }
            finally { timer.Start(); }
    }
```